# Spark join - (edges and vertices)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `vertexRDD` which has 2 columns

```
(vertexId, uniqueVertexId)
(V1, 1L)
(V2, 2L)
(V3, 3L)
(V4, 4L)
```

And I also have `edgeRDD`

```
(srcId, destId)
(V1, V2)
(V2, V3)
(V1, V4)
```

How can I join them in spark so the edges RDD will be like below

```
(srcId, destId, uniqueSrcId, uniqueDestId)
(V1, V2, 1L, 2L)
(V2, V3, 2L, 3L)
(V1, V4, 1L, 4L)
```

I tried different joins but I couldn't really achieve the expected output. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Java but I guess it is straightforward to convert it to Scala.
Assuming
`edgeRDD` has type `JavaPairRDD<String,String>` and
`vertexRDD` has type `JavaPairRDD<String,Long>`:

1. `edgeRDD.join(vertexRDD)` will yield `JavaPairRDD<String,Tuple2<String,Long>>` with the following content (let's call it `join1`):

   ```
   (V1, Tuple2(V2,1L)) 
   (V2, Tuple2(V3,2L))
   (V1, Tuple2(V4,1L))
   ```
2. Then you convert `join1` into another `JavaPairRDD<String,Tuple2<String,Long>>` by restructuring the keys and values using map (let's call it `join2`):

   ```
   (V2, Tuple2(V1,1L)) 
   (V3, Tuple2(V2,2L))
   (V4, Tuple2(V1,1L))
   ```
3. Finally perform `vertexRDD.join(join2)` to get `JavaPairRDD<String,Tuple2<Long,Tuple2<String,Long>>>` with contents:

   ```
   (V2, Tuple2(2L, Tuple2(V1,1L)))
   (V3, Tuple2(3L, Tuple2(V2,2L)))
   (V4, Tuple2(4L, Tuple2(V1,1L)))
   ```

which you may pass through the map and create `JavaRDD<String>` (or a new `JavaPairRDD`) by combining keys and values appropriately within the map. I will leave mapping phases up to you.